# Is there a regular expression to find two different words in a sentence?

Tags: visual-studio, regex, string, search, find

Is there a regular expression to find two different words in a sentence?  Extra credit for an expression that works in MS Visual Studio 2008 :)

For example:

```
reg_ex_match(A, B, "A sentence with A and B") = true
reg_ex_match(C, D, "A sentence with A and B") = false
```

See also this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/210518/regex-multi-word-search)

Comment: Try giving a complete example of what you want to happen? Is it OR or AND you require?  What range of characters are allowed in A, B, C and D?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “word”? A sequence that is either delimited by space characters or at the begin or the end of the string?

Answer (score 10):

For real words:

```
\bA\b.+\bB\b|\bB\b.+\bA\b
```

Comment: I guess it depends on what is meant by "words" by the OP. And, the second half of your expression is double B's.

Comment: Also, note that a word boundary may not be what you want. To the OP, is "A-B" one word or two every time? Ex: a last name is sometimes hyphenated.

Answer (score 3):

".*A.*B.*|.*B.*A.*"
You can add spaces around the words A and B if you want proper words.

Comment: Careful. This would match "The sentence with AB". Close, though.

Comment: Which would be a proper behaviour
If you define a word as a separate word, then as I said you should add spaces around.

Comment: Spaces won't cut it, because a word might be at the beginning or the end of the String. In that case it should still be considered a separate word, but hasn't got a space before/after it. See @Gumbos solution using \b for the "real" solution.

Comment: Be careful with word boundaries. I've seen lots of people get bitten by not realizing that some "words" they had in their dataset contained characters not in the boundary definition for whatever "flavor" of regex they were using.

Comment: This would also match AUTOBAHN or BAILOUT since the .* will also match word characters that surround or are in between the A and B (or B and A). It would even match something like "And always be sure to look both ways BEFORE crossing the street."

Answer (score 0):

Why not use boolean logic, rather than a complicated regex?

Code not tested:

```
public bool reg_ex_match(Regex A, Regex B, string s) {
    return A.isMatch(s) && B.isMatch(s);
}
```

Update: This assumes A and B are defined with word boundaries:

```
Regex A = new Regex(@"\bA\b");
```

Comment: This doesn't work if A="foo" and B="foomator" then it will return true for "this is foomator".

Answer (score 0):

`.*A.*\s.*B.*|.*B.*\s.*A.*`

Please note the use of the '+' between A and B. This is to ensure you match on separate A and B. If this is not a requirement, then Łukasz Lew's answer is correct.

UPDATE: Changed as per Bryan's excellent observation below. The above expression will recognize A separated from B (or vice versa) with at least one whitespace character (space, tab or line break) between the two regions of interest.

Comment: Assuming the sentence is not split by a line break character. (Since that would not match the '.')

Comment: You probably meant .\*A.+B.\*|.\*B.+A.\*

Comment: Not really. That is proper regex syntax, although it may need to be adapted to whatever environment you use it in...

Comment: What I meant is that you need "\" to make * appear in your answer :)

Comment: If you're talking about preventing the asterisk from being interpreted as markup, the proper way is either to enclose the text in `backticks`, or to put it on its own line, indented four spaces.

Comment: This has the same issue as Lukasz Lew's regex. It will match unintended targets like AMBIENT or BLANK.

Answer (score 0):

### Regex

Following regex matches the entire string, only if the string contains all of the words: `all your words here`. You can easily add other words or remove existing ones.

```
(?=.*?\ball\b)
(?=.*?\byour\b)
(?=.*?\bwords\b)
(?=.*?\bhere\b)
.*
```

Not so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

The **regex expression** you are looking for is something like this:

```
/word1.*(?=word2)|word2.*(?=word1)/igm
```

This is also **case insenitive** and can be applied to text that is **multiline**.

*Tested over at http://regexr.com/*

Answer (score -1):

Try searching [regexlib](http://regexlib.com), a regular expression repository.

Comment: This is bad advice anyway.  The quality of regexes on that site is all over the place, and peer review is almost non-existent.