# How do you find all files with two separate words?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, find

In VS2010, what would be the regular expression for 'Find in Files' to search for all source files that contain two separate words regardless of line breaks?

For Example I want to find any source file that contains 'This' and 'That'.

I tried something like this but it did not work:

((This).* \n* .*(That))

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520252/is-there-a-regular-expression-to-find-two-different-words-in-a-sentence

Comment: That response talks about using regex in code. I am wanting to use VS2010 to search my code.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

'this' followed by anything including newline followed by 'that',
or
'that' followed by anything including newline followed by 'this':

```
((this)(.*\n)*.*(that))|((that)(.*\n)*.*(this))
```

Comment: That works if the words are on the same line. I'm trying to find the magic that will find the files were they are one or more lines apart.

Comment: Updated answer. Regex longer than about 10 chars makes me feel sick though, but it seemed to work for me.

Answer (score 3):

I find it easier to just do this, eg:

```
select|insert|update|delete
```

Note: VS's search needs to be set to use regular expressions.
The order of the words does not matter.

So, we end up with something like this:
[image]

EDIT:
To find a list, just do "Entire Solution", and then "Find all".
[image]

[image]

Comment: The question was how to list files containing all search terms.

Comment: Then you just do a "Find all files" instead of "Current Document" - and you have your list in VS :)

Comment: You have still failed to answer the question. The vertical line character is disjunction (meaning matches term A or term B), but OP asked to match on files containing ALL search terms (meaning matches term A and term B).